# Can I upgrade an ASP.NET web service to WCF and still call it from ASP.NET 1.1?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I need to make a change to an ASP.NET web service written a couple years ago on 2.0.  I call this web service from an old 1.1 web site.  I need to make some changes to the web service, so am thinking, should I rewrite this into a WCF service and if so, will I still be able to use it from my 1.1 web site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this will work.  Your service will need to be at least .net 3.0, but as long as you use a basicHttpBinding or wsHttpBinding, you can consume it like any other webservice.

Comment: True... Only BasicHttpBinding as far as I have seen.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a WCF service act and behave just like a traditional 1.1 ASMX web service, but is that what you want?

I think you need to ask yourself what featires of WCF are motivating you to upgrade.
Do you want to also expose the service as a REST-ful service?  Do you need to implement message level security?

If it's just to go to the latest technology for the sake of the latest technology, I'd say stick with ASMX web services if your requirements for message and protocol security aren't that high and you're working with mostly microsoft technologies.

Writing a WCF service is regrettably more difficult than a plain-old asmx web service.

Comment: Great food for thought.  Right now, no, I don't need the enhanced features of WCF, but if I get a basic service going, I can expand it later.  I really want to know if I can use it from 1.1 or if there are any gotchas.

Comment: Yup, wcf is a world of config pain, stick to asmx

Comment: I'd like to now modify my previous comment... With WCF in .Net 4.0, the config can be as simple as a traditional asmx service.  See here for details:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx

Answer (score 0):

yes you can... make sure to choose the correct bindings and authentication methods